# android - where does WebView download its files to?

Tags: android, file, webview, download, offline

I am implementing a simple download system in the embedded webview, by intercepting the click using shouldOverrideUrlLoading and then call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW ,Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

This opens the native browser, shows an indicator that the file is being downloaded, and once it's completed I can pull down the notification list to view the file. I have several questions though:

1. Where does WebView download its files to?
2. Is this a temporary cache or is it persistent? Can I access it offline?
3. How can my WebView gets informed when the download completes?

Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is that, once the file is downloaded, the next time the user clicks to the link, it will open up the local downloaded file, instead of trying to download it again.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the emulator through the DDMS perspective in Eclipse it looks like the files are downloaded to either yourAppsNamespace/cache/webviewCache or actually into the yourAppsNamespace/databases/ . So the file should be a permanent download. As to knowing when the download is complete i am not sure